# Kobold2d and Cocos Builder: setting start scene

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

In Kobold2d certain functions that in Cocos2d is in the appDelegate is in a config.lua file. And this brings me to the problem cause to initialize a Cocos Builder as the first scene in cocos2d you replace this line (in the app delegate)

```
[director runWithScene: [IntroLayer scene]];
```

with

```
[director runWithScene: [CCBReader sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile:@"MainMenuScene.ccbi"]];
```

but this is all hidden away in Kobold2d - replaced by `FirstSceneClassName = "HelloWorldLayer"` in the config.lua file.

Anyone knows a bugfree way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use runWithScene, just put it in AppDelegate's `initializationComplete` method. This will take precedence over loading the scene specified in config.lua.

Comment: Thanks! that worked! then I found out Cocos Builder is not ARC Compliant :(. tried setting compiler flag to compile it as non-arc code, but still no success. I´ll just leave it for now.